# CSS Select element with inline and/or parent style (or class)

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class, direction, register-transfer-level

I have a document like this:

```
<html>
  ...
  <body style="direction: rtl;">
    <div class="col-ml-auto">
      some elements following body's direction
    </div>
    ...
    <div class="col-ml-auto" style="direction: ltr;">
      some elements forced to be ltr
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I can select parent directioned elements using this syntax:

```
.col-ml-auto{margin-left:auto}
[style*="rtl"] .col-ml-auto{margin-left:unset;margin-right:auto}
```

It selects normal elements but inline direction has no effect.

I can select inline directioned elements using this syntax:

```
.col-ml-auto{margin-left:auto}
.col-ml-auto[style*="rtl"]{margin-left:unset;margin-right:auto}
```

It selects inline directioned elements but don't select parent directioned ones, so how to handle both?

Comment: So you want any element whose direction is `rtl`? If so there is the [`dir:()` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:dir). Otherwise, could you try to be even more explicit, e.g with some HTML sample.

Comment: @Kaiido Unfortunately `dir:()` checks the html's `dir` not css's `direction`, however little number of browsers support this pseudo-class. I updated the question with an example.

Comment: putting attempts aside for a moment, exactly what is the point? what do you want to get as final result?

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan selecting elements per inline direction > per parent direction > default direction (just like how browsers render an element)

Answer (score 0):

You won't have a selector based on something CSS can set, this would create a loop. For instance if we had an hypothetical `:direction()` pseudo-selector that was sensitive to the direction set by CSS, a rule like `:direction(ltr) { direction: rtl; }` would block the engine.

But then, even if all your direction rules are set in inline `style=""` attributes, and even if you are sure you will *never* have something like `style="direction:rtl; direction: ltr;"`, I doubt you'll find a selector able to tell apart the elements that are the closest of a parent matching *A* and the ones that are closer to a *B*.

So your best bet might be to make use of inheritance here, and for instance to declare all the styles you want to set as `--css-variables`. Then, (still assuming all the directions are set through `style=""` attributes), you can do something like

```css
[style*=direction][style*=rtl] {
  --rule-1: rtl-value
}
[style*=direction][style*=ltr] {
  --rule-1: ltr-value;
}
```

```css
[style*=direction][style*=rtl] {
  --rule-1: green
}
[style*=direction][style*=ltr] {
  --rule-1: red;
}

* {
  border: 1px solid var(--rule-1);
}
```

```html
<body style="direction: rtl;">
  <div class="col-ml-auto">
    some elements following body's direction
  </div>
  ...
  <div class="col-ml-auto" style="direction: ltr;">
    some elements forced to be ltr
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it would make many fundamental changes in my css. There isn't a way to detect current rendering direction of element?

Comment: None that I know, no. But I'm curious what fundamental changes in your CSS that would make. For instance given the rules you shown in your question that would be `[style*=direction][style*=rtl] { --margin-left: auto; --margin-right: unset; } [style*=direction][style*=ltr] { --margin-left: unset; --margin-right: auto; } .col-ml-auto{ margin-left: var(--margin-left); margin-right: var(--margin-right) }`

Comment: I'm working on rtl feature for [Spectre](https://github.com/picturepan2/spectre) framework. I don't know if there is a standard way for making css frameworks bidirectional.